# dll hijacking Related Questions

Tags: browser-hijacking

I read a about "dll hijacking" technology.

This usually occurs in the installation directory.(% Program Files%)

But, It is not possible to plant a DLL file in the "% Program Files%" path.

Because need UAC privilege.

Why is this a security issue?

As I understand it, it requires high interaction.

Thanks

Comment: Everything is possible and UAC is relatively simple to bypass..check this out https://www.greyhathacker.net/?p=796

Comment: Hijacking can be done by placing a DLL in the same directory as the executable (maybe even shortcut?).

Comment: @forest exactly,
Usually, however, the executable is installed in the path "% Program Files%".
So, in order to plant a DLL, should be able to put the file in "%Program Files%".

Comment: @SoufianeTahiri Thanks for the good info.
I have a question.
Suppose that DLL hijacking is vulnerable to "C:\Program Files\pizza\Bin\count.exe" 
"count.exe" loads the DLL file in the current path ("C:\Program Files\pizza\Bin\").
If so, how can I put the DLL file in the path?
The opera decided not to consider these types of problems as a security issue. (link:https://blogs.opera.com/security/2017/03/dll-hijacking-opera-browser/)

Comment: I think this problem should be linked to the "Weak Service Permissions" issue in order to be a security issue.